# Automapper 2 - unflattening entity to VM

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, automapper, automapper-2

I have a flat POCO Entity and a structured View Model (that is used for rendering a form with custom EditorFor helpers).

Is there any easier way in Automapper 2 to do something like that:

```
cfg.CreateMap<TelcoDemand, TelcoDemandViewModel>()
.ForMember(d => d.Person, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(s => new PersonViewModel
    {
        FirstName = s.PersonFirstName,
        LastName = s.PersonLastName,
        Phone = s.PersonPhone,
        Email = s.PersonEmail
    }))
.ForMember(d => d.AddressContact, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(s => new AddressViewModel
    {
        City = s.AddressContactCity,
        HouseNumber = s.AddressContactHouseNumber,
        Street = s.AddressContactStreet,
        Zip = s.AddressContactZip
    }))
.ForMember(d => d.AddressCourier, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(s => new AddressViewModel
    {
        City = s.AddressCourierCity,
        HouseNumber = s.AddressCourierHouseNumber,
        Street = s.AddressCourierStreet,
        Zip = s.AddressCourierZip
    }))
.ForMember(d => d.Address, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(s => new AddressViewModel
    {
        City = s.AddressCity,
        HouseNumber = s.AddressHouseNumber,
        Street = s.AddressStreet,
        Zip = s.AddressZip
    }))
```

What I am trying to achieve is to unflatten Person and Address fields into a viewmodel that then gets rendered using a EditorFor.

Flattening it back to database works great, but there is no way I could get the unflattening working by convention...

**Edit**

I have also a IgnoreAllUnexisting extension used here, it's implemented like that:

```
public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> IgnoreAllNonExisting<TSource, TDestination>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> expression)
{
    var sourceType = typeof(TSource);
    var destinationType = typeof(TDestination);
    var existingMaps = Mapper.GetAllTypeMaps().First(x => x.SourceType == sourceType && x.DestinationType == destinationType);
    foreach (var property in existingMaps.GetUnmappedPropertyNames())
    {
        expression.ForMember(property, opt => opt.Ignore());
    }
    expression.ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition(src => !src.IsSourceValueNull));
    return expression;
}
```

Anyway I also tried it without that extension, and the result was just the same - bunch of null values in the complex types.

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions when you try to unflatten by convention? Or do you just end up with a bunch of nulls in your `TelcoDemandViewModel` instance?

Comment: I just end up with a bunch of nulls. See the original post, I added some more explanation.

Comment: Just to clarify, are the null values on your `TelcoDemandViewModel` instance, or on the nested `PersonViewModel` and `AddressViewModel` instances? If on the former, have you tried instantiating the Person & Address viewmodels in the TelcoDemand viewmodel constructor?

Comment: I am asserting `td.Address.City` in my unit tests and I am getting no Null reference exception, so the nested VMs are instantiated correctly. Actually I have them in the constructor already.

So the null values are in the nested instances' properties.